# How can a Wordpress plugin knows its own position?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to write a plugin and in this plugin, it needs to know its current position in the whole file system. I tried the code like below:

```
var Path = location.hostName + '/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/';
```

but when I use this plugin in a post named 'test', the Path turns out to be:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/test/undefined/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/
```

How can I correct this and make it like:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/
```

I am not sure if I have put it clear. Please help...thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [plugin_dir_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) function:

```
<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>
```

Would echo:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Sorry that I have another question. Is there a way to pass this value to Javascript?

Comment: I just found this which might help: http://www.webtipblog.com/localize-scripts-in-wordpress-to-use-php-variables-in-javascript/ ... thank @rnevius for your help!

Comment: Where is the JavaScript? Is it in a JS file, or directly in your PHP template??

Comment: Update your question with your code for enqueue script.

Comment: [This may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)...although I'm really curious about your use case here...It sounds odd to need this in JS.